# WCF Сервис для доступа к базе данных через EntityFramework

Tags: c#, wcf

Я бы хоте посоветоваться с вами. Смотрите, такая ситуация, я создал отдельно бд и сгенерил dbmx используя Entity Framework (Database First). Так я имею где то 10 таблиц, к которым сервис обязан давать доступ в случае получение некоторого запроса от клиента. Вот тут я пытаюсь разобраться как мне реализовать возможность доступа к разным частям таблицы. Знаю, что существует такая штука как WCF Data Service, которая бы решила мои проблемы, но я пользуюсь VS 2017, в которой нету возможности юзать WCF Data Service, по этому этот вариант отбрасываю. Дальше я думал сделать таким образом, чтобы создать на стороне сервиса некоторые трансляторы Data Contract для каждой таблицы и задать методы для приведения сущностей созданных EntityFramework-м к "транслируемым". Это честно говоря максимум на что хватило моих познаний.

Является ли такой подход приемлемым, и еще, если найдутся люди, кто реализовал подобные схемы, я был бы крайне признателен, если бы вы мне скинули исходники этих примеров(понимаю, что много прошу), это бы гараздо сильно бы упростило и ускорило мое изучение данной технологии, спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Вам сервис нужен для чего? Кто его вызывать удет и как? Он вам точно нужен?

Comment: Сервис будет хоститься службой виндовс, биндинг tcp, нужен мне он, чтобы обеспечить связь между сервером на котором стоит MS SQL Server, и клиентом на другом компе.

Comment: Ну соотвественно, я буду давать запрос на клиенте на выполнения операций Select, Update, Insert, Delete. То есть это WPF приложения информационной системы в качестве клиента, и WCF в службе виндовс + MS SQL Server в качестве сервера.

Comment: В таком случае, чтобы сделать все правильно, вам надо сначала продумать API вашего сервиса, а потом, основываясь на уже продуманном API решить как хранить данные

Comment: я немного не понял, что подразумевается под "продумать Api". У меня есть сгенерированные EntityFramework сущности для доступа к базе данных и я хочу понять как организовать доступ к этим данным в самом WCF сервисе. То есть вот у меня есть идея с "трансляторами". Может есть какой то подход для решения подобных задач? Ну то есть, я примерно это вижу как создать кучу контрактов которые реализовывают Insert, Update, Delete, Select для каждой таблицы MS SQL Server через использование контекста EntityFramework.

Comment: Я правильно вас понял, что WCF вы собираетесь использовать в качестве прокси к базе? Если да, то не делайте этого. Я уже намучился с таким решением, благо не сам придумал, наследство свалилось. Нет, реализовать такое можно, но вот готовы ли вы реализовать полноценный интерфейс ADO.NET провайдера на WCF? Если не готовы, то пишите нормальный API на WCF, и всю работу с БД прячьте за этим API. Нормальный API дает намного больше преимуществ как по скорости разработки, так и по расширяемости, работы тоже достаточно, но пользы от нее больше

Comment: А если вам нужен просто доступ к БД с удаленного компа, так проще расшарить БД, а не плодить сервисы.

Comment: @tym32167 это сложный вопрос, тогда придется держать строку подключения на стороне клиента. а это не всегда хорошо или вообще возможно. Ну либо строку подключения отдавать после авторизации на независимом сервисе.

Comment: @rdorn у него же SQL Server, он может юзать встроенную авторизацию с ролями и прочими плюхами. Но надо ли оно ему или нет - вот вопрос

Comment: @tym32167 вот я и говорю, что сложный =) раз однозначно верного решения нет. У меня сейчас базу трогать вообще нельзя из-за легаси-кода, который активно юзвери пользуют, приходится извращаться

Comment: Я честно говоря не могу понять, что имеется ввиду под написаем API. То есть имеется ввиду написание библиотеки классов\интерфейсов для работы с нужной мне бд, я правильно понял? Насчет ролей, роли пользователей у меня есть, некоторым разрешен только просмотр, некоторым просмотр и добавление данных и тд. Ну эту логику я собирался прописывать на стороне сервера, проверяя цифровую подпись для того, чтобы идентифицировать роль юзера.

Answer (score 3):

Каждый сервис разрабоатывается для какой то цели. 
Рассмотрим пример. Например, у нас есть клиент (установленный на клиентской машине) и ему надо знать текущее время. Использовать время компьютера, где установлен клиент, нельзя, так как время на клиенте может спешить\отставать. Так у нас появляется необходимость написать свой сервис, который вернет текущее время. Что этот сервис ещё может сделать? Вернуть текущее время определенного часового пояса, установленного на клиентском компьютере. Так у нас появляются методы

```
DateTime GetCurrentTime(string timeZone);
DateTime GetCurrentTimeUTC();
```

^^ это АПИ нового сервиса. То есть контракт, котрого сервис придерживается. Здесь нет описания, как новый сервис обрабатывает эти запросы. Здесь не важно, как сервис хранит временные зоны. Здесь не важно, как сервис сам получает текущее время. Это все не имеет значения для клиента. Клиенту достаточно видеть эти 2 метода и вызывать тот, который ему необходим.

То, что было выше, можно рассматривать как базовые требования к новому сервису. Далее, когда дело доходит до реализации сервиса, там уже разработчику надо думать, что и как ему нужно хранить, как и что обрабатывать, какую БД использовать и прочие ньюансы, которые клиенту сервиса абсолютно безразлины и неведомы. Это нормальный процесс разарботки сервисов.

Вы же идете в обратном направлении. Вы пытаетесь по схеме построенной БД создать сервис. *Это неверно*, так не надо делать. Что бы я хотел вам посоветовать:

1. Определитесь с требованиями для вашего сервиса. Что ваш сервис должен делать, какие методы вашего сервиса клиент захочет вызывать.
2. Основываясь на п.1 постройте API вашего сервиса. То есть определитесь с набором методов и требованиям к ним.
3. Основываясь на п.2 начните реализацию вашего сервиса. Тут уже не важно, Code-First у вас или вы в файлике все храните. Это не имеет эначения для клиента - это имеет значение только для разработчика сервиса, так как разработчик должен сделать все, чтобы опубликованный API (или ещё его наывают контракт) выполнялся и клиент при вызовал этого АПИ получал то, что ожидается получить при вызове АПИ.

А база данных или способ хранения информации никогда не должен влиять на предоставляемый вашим сервисом АПИ, так как сегодня у вас SQL Server, завтра эффективные менеджеры попросят все переписать на Postgres, послезватра маркетологи запросят переделать по Mongodb.

Comment: Да суть задачи уяснил, буду работать над этим